# Shift after reprojection from EPSG:3035 to other EPSG CRS (25832 / 31467 / 4326)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdalwarp, utm

I'm trying to reproject a raster layer (EPSG:3035) to EPSG:25832.
In QGIS I used gdalwarp with the following command:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:3035 -t_srs EPSG:25832 -tr 30.0 30.0 -r near -of GTiff disturbance_year_1986-2020_germany.tif OUTPUT.tif
```

I visualize the data in ArcGIS Pro and QGIS with a background map (Google Maps / Google Satellite), but there is a shift between the raster layer in EPSG:3035 and EPSG:25832.

My question: Is this because of displaying the data (OTF-transformation in QGIS, project set to EPSG:25832), or is there a problem with the reprojection I did?

The shift varies in direction and extent, pixel size is in both layers 30m.

[image: Shift between layers]

The original data is this Forest Disturbance Map:
https://zenodo.org/record/7080016#.Y-TuL3bMKVk
=> Germany.zip --> disturbance_year_1986-2020_germany.tif

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Thank you, Ian. I added some details about the command I was using to do the reprojection and rephrased the question clearer.

Comment: so you have the same data in two projections and then you project both data sets to 3587 and are surprised that they don't line up? TBH I would expect there to be a difference. Try reprojecting one into the other's projection

Comment: No, I have one raster layer (EPSG:3035) which I reproject into EPSG:25832. If I then load both layers in QGIS/ArcGIS, they are not matching completely. I know that a 100% exact reprojection of raster data is not possible, but I measured differences of ~10-13 meters.
(I deleted the additional phrase about EPSG:4326 and 31467, it was possibly misleading information in the question).

Comment: You might compare the datum transformations you used in your reprojection and those being used on the fly.  If they differ you would have an offset.